# Remove white space from file - preserve one line

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and trying to remove white space from a file. The file contains some values and has white spaces (indentation):

```
Hostname=hostname1
Server=server1
Directory=C:\Program Files\Test
Database=db1
```

I am trying to remove white space, but preserve the "directory" line as it contains a whitespace in the path `C:\Program Files\Test` and this will break the build. This is the code I have so far:

```
foreach ($Line in (Get-Content -Path C:\File.txt) | Where-Object {$_ -notcontains "Directory"}) {
    $line -replace " ", ""
    Set-Content -Path C:\File.txt
}
```

But this produces an empty file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try this `(Get-Content C:\file.txt) -replace '^\s+', ''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Set-Content` receives input either via the pipeline or via the parameter `-Value`. Your code doesn't provide either, so the cmdlet is writing an empty file. Also, your processing would entirely remove all lines containing the string "Directory" from the output.

Change your code to something like this and the problem will disappear:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\File.txt') | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -notlike 'Directory=*') {
        $_ -replace ' ', ''
    } else {
        $_
    }
} | Set-Content 'C:\File.txt'
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's only a matter of removing indentation you could use the `Trim`-function:

```
$fileContent = Get-Content C:\File.txt
$fileContent | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() } | Set-Content C:\File.txt
```

The `Trim`-function removes only leading and trailing white space. There is also a `TrimStart` and `TrimEnd` if you only want to remove either leading or trailing white space.

Note: The content of the file is first stored in a variable to release the lock on the file system before `Set-Content` is called. If you use a different output file you can pipe the result of `Get-Content` directly into the `ForEach-Object`.